# MySQL table issue with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, string, codeigniter, offset

This page was previously displaying properly. I don't see anything wrong with the specified line number in this error message. I just did a few edits on some code snippets based on what I saw in different tutorials online.

I went back through each revision I made but I still don't see anything that could have affected this function/part.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Uninitialized string offset: 0
>
> Filename: client/view_job.php
>
> Line Number: 75

Here's what I have on line 75:

```
<a href="<?= site_url() ?>/client/edit_job/<?= $row['job_id'] ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-lg active" role="button">Edit</a>
```

This was perfectly displayed before. I don't know where the new issue came from.

Comment: Are you sure `$row['job_id']` returns some value ?

Comment: To make sure that it was not about anything I revised both in my controller and model page,  I cut the revised ones and restored my old /original copy. But still, I got the issue. In terms of config, the only things I changed were autoload url and form as well as database and session libraries. I don't think they affected line 75 either. I don't know what went wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hsuk, I realized your point and I could actually solve it by changing

```
$row['job_id']
```

to simply

```
<?= $id?>
```

and it worked..